# C#: DateTime.UtcNow changes to local time after assigning to object

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

There's not much that's really that remarkable about my code. Here's basically what I'm concerned about.

Node.cs

```
public class Node {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastCheckin { get; set; }
}
```

NodeUpdateReceiver.cs Get's fired by an EventHandler. `Process` is provided with a `Node`

```
public class NodeUpdateReceiver {

    IDatabaseService databaseService { get; }

    public NodeUpdateReceiver(IDatabaseService _dataService)
    {
        dataService = _dataService;
    }

    public async Task Process(Node node)
    {
        var newDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        Console.WriteLine(newDate); // 5/23/2018 1:58:41 PM - correct UTC

        node.LastCheckin = newDate;
        Console.WriteLine(node.LastCheckin) // 5/23/2018 9:25:19 AM - local time... wtf??

        dataService.SaveNodeAsync(node);
    } 
}
```

How in the hell can that happen? What am I missing about assigning this DateTime that converts it to local time? Any pointers or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/GCZZ51723)

Comment: Odd behavior `5/23/2018 1:58:41 PM` and `5/23/2018 9:25:19 AM` can not be UTC to local conversion. I don't think time difference between any two zones in less than 30 mins. If difference between mentioned dates are around 4 h 33 M and few secs. How't it possible.

Comment: @user Indeed. OP needs to provide an [mcve].

Comment: Just deleted my answer, as I also cannot reproduce - are you missing some code? I copied as-is, and get `23/05/2018 14:07:22` output for both

Comment: @john Yes, sorry. I had massively simplified my example. Did not verify it. However, Alex's [now deleted] answer did solve it. I tried using it before posting the question, but it didn't work. For some reason, after I changed `LastCheckin` to `DateTime?` and cast it back to `DateTime` it worked. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: i've un-deleted it.... if you can enrich your question, i'll edit the answer to reflect

Comment: @Alex, yes. I didn't verify that this example would reproduce. It's a much-abridged version of my actual project. Your solution of `.ToUniversalTime()` somehow did it this time, even though it didn't before I asked this question, after I switched it to `DateTime?`

Comment: @user1672994 _I don't think time difference between any two zones in less than 30 mins_ Don't be sure about that. There are timezones that have `..:45` as a UTC offset like Nepal and Chatham Islands for example :)

Comment: What's the output of `Console.WriteLine(newDate.Kind);` and `Console.WriteLine(node.LastCheckin.Kind);` respectively?

Comment: `Local` and `Utc`, as suspected

Comment: @SonerGönül - I noticed after posting my comment about 15 min diff between two time zones. But point I was making that the mentioned date difference is odd and can not be conversion form UTC to local.

Comment: @Nickdb93 - so apparently your real code is not as simple as the one you posted. Thus right now we can't help you find where exactly the flag/bit for UTC is lost.

Comment: @Corak Indeed. And it is appears to be something to do with my database service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`node.LastCheckin` is of type DateTime

What you're seeing when you do:

```
Console.WriteLine(node.LastCheckin);
```

Is the local representation of that instance of `DateTime`
If that were to be executed on a different machine, with a different TimeZone, you'd see another result (still offset to UTC)

To get UTC back out, you'll need to use `.ToUniversalTime()`

```
Console.WriteLine(node.LastCheckin.ToUniversalTime());
```

Comment: @john this fixed the problem, but the DateTime is taken from the same process.

Comment: Why would `Console.WriteLine(newDate);` then be "correct", while `Console.WriteLine(node.LastCheckin);` isn't?

Comment: @Corak - it appears the OP supplied an over-simplified example

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it was something specific to my Database of choice (**LiteDB**, not shown in my example). I should have included it.

It's unclear what happened exactly. I can't seem to find a reason why, but the UTC time was being stored as Local time. Alex's suggestion of using `check.ToUniversalTime()` to evaluate the DateTime worked.

This github issue talks about some of the DateTime complexities involved with LiteDB, but not mine specifically:
https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/794

Comment: glad you got it sorted, devil is usually in the detail with these things!

Comment: @Alex thank you sir. Of course it is... I accepted your answer btw. You pointed it out first, even when I didn't think that could be it.